# Filtering files during copy command in snowflake running in snowpipe

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have the files /abc_date_time, /def_abc_date_time, /xyz_abc_date_time present in stage. While creating snowpipe i want data to be ingested only from /abc_date_time file however the snowpipe does not run when '/' character is specified in pattern. The file name is coming with the entire s3 bucket path[ ex - s3://bucket_name/folder_name/abc_date_time, s3://bucket_name/folder_name/def_abc_date_time and s3://bucket_name/folder_name/xyz_abc_date_time]. How do I filter only /abc_date_time file in the snowpipe.

```
create pipe mypipe as
copy into table_name from
(select $1,$2,metadata$file_name from @stage/folder_name/)
file format = (type='csv')
pattern = '.*/abc_*[0-9].*.csv'
```

Comment: Your filenames don't actually have an initial "/" as part of their names, do they? Assuming they don't, I'm not sure why you are including the slash in the filename pattern? Doesn't this work: pattern = 'abc_*[0-9].csv'